# Synchronizing of Threadpool

Tags: c++, multithreading

In every time step multiple worker threadss W[1..10] are supposed to idle until they are signaled from the main thread to start working. Do each their work, Signal back to the mainthread that they are done and return to the waiting state they were in before. The mainthread is supposed to be waiting while the workerthreads do their work.

I was trying to do this using `std::condition_variable` ann `std::mutex` but failed. What is the right approach to the problem not using boost or other high Level libraries? *I would like to avoid spawning and joining threads in every step for performance reasons.* Thank you very much.

Edit:

```
const size_t thread_num = 10;

int busy_count = thread_num;

std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex cv_m;

std::condition_variable cv_lock1;
std::mutex cv_m_lock1;


bool lock_1;

bool end_all = false;

void wthread()
{   
    do {        
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_m_lock1);
            cv_lock1.wait(lk, []{return lock_1 == false; });
        }

        if (end_all)
        {
            std::cout << "exit\n";
            return;
        }

        // do work

        {           
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
            busy_count--;
            std::cout << busy_count << " ";         
        }       
        cv.notify_all();

        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_m_lock1);
            cv_lock1.wait(lk, []{return lock_1 == true; });
        }



    } while (true);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{       
    std::thread *t[thread_num];

    lock_1 = true;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < thread_num; i++)
        t[i] = new std::thread(wthread);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        busy_count = 10;            

        lock_1 = false;     
        cv_lock1.notify_all();      

        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
            cv.wait(lk, []{return busy_count == 0; });
        }

        lock_1 = true;      
        cv_lock1.notify_all();
    }

    end_all = true;
    lock_1 = false; 
    cv_lock1.notify_all();  


    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < thread_num; i++)
        t[i]->join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The right approach is to change your design to avoid that. It's exactly the sort of situation you most want to avoid in multi-threaded code.

Comment: _"I was trying to do this using std::condition_variable ann std::mutex but failed."_ That's the usual way to do it. May be you should show us here what you dud specifically and where it failed.

Comment: I've added the Code. How would you Change the design? I'm happy with being pointed into the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
std::thread thread1([](){/*do something*/});
std::thread thread2([](){/*do something*/});
std::thread thread3([](){/*do something*/});
thread1.join();
thread2.join();
thread3.join();
```

main thread will wait until threads 1..3 finish working; and those threads will be working simultaneously

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is pretty much how I've done it before but I realized that spawning and joining threads has a pretty large overhead (around 2-3ms) and I was hoping to avoid that by having the worker threads be persistent.